# Hybrid of slider with progress bar JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, desktop

I want to handle click on ProgressBar like on slider. and learn a percent of track. 
I would use slider instead progressbar but it doesn't have a highlighted track until thumb.

I need create something like a progress in a music player of playing song, and possibility to seek with a click on progress.

Do anybody have a tips how can i do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried to find a customization with css. But google gave nothing. Documentation doesn't have a css references for substructure like a thumb and track.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is another approach. Real hybrid of slider and progress bar :). Meet SlidoProgressBar!

```
public class SlidoProgressBarDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Progress Controls");

        double sliderWidth = 200;

        final Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setMin(0);
        slider.setMax(50);
        slider.setMinWidth(sliderWidth);
        slider.setMaxWidth(sliderWidth);

        final ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0);
        pb.setMinWidth(sliderWidth);
        pb.setMaxWidth(sliderWidth);

        final ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(0);

        slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                    Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                pb.setProgress(new_val.doubleValue() / 50);
                pi.setProgress(new_val.doubleValue() / 50);
            }
        });

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();

        pane.getChildren().addAll(pb, slider);

        final HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setSpacing(5);
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(pane, pi);

        scene.setRoot(hb);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with style.css:

```
.slider .track {
    -fx-background-color:null;  /* Hide the track */
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 2.5, 2.5, 1.5;
    -fx-padding: 0.208333em; /* 2.5 */
}
```

The basic logic is to put slider and progress into stackpane. Give them the same width. Bind the progress values of them. Hide the track of the slider.
Output:
[image]

Comment: Haha, I thought about it. but i think it will work with random chance. How do you know where You click? on slider or pb?

Comment: @Vetal.lebed. Stackpane puts its children overlapped each other so that the last added child is on the top of others. Thus it is always the slider (and its invisible track) that gets the mouse click. Moreover progress bar is not clickable by default.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it. I am an android developer.

Comment: great ptototype, but unfortunately the progressbar doesn't quite match with the slider in the first 30%. And I can't seem to make out the purpose of `-fx-background-insets` and `-fx-background-radius` in this context

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem with code :

```
progress.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY){
                Bounds b1 = progress.getLayoutBounds();
                double mouseX = event.getSceneX();
                double percent = (((b1.getMinX() + mouseX ) * 100) / b1.getMaxX());
                //correcting a percent, i don't know when it need
                percent -= 2;
                progress.setProgress((percent) / 100);
                //do something with progress in percent
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tornadoFX example:

```
package bj

import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.geometry.Insets
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar
import javafx.scene.control.Slider
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
import tornadofx.*

/**
* Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 18-12-13 下午9:28
*/

class MainView : View() {

    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var slider: Slider

    override val root = vbox {
        stackpane {
            padding = Insets(100.0)
            progressbar(initialValue = .0) {
                progressBar = this
                maxWidth = Double.MAX_VALUE
            }
            slider(max = 1, value = .0) {
                slider = this
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty())
        progressBar.paddingLeftProperty.bind(progressBar.heightProperty().divide(2))
        progressBar.paddingRightProperty.bind(progressBar.heightProperty().divide(2))
    }
}

class MainStylesheet : Stylesheet() {
    init {
        slider {
            track {
                backgroundColor = MultiValue(arrayOf(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            }
        }
    }

}

class App : tornadofx.App(MainView::class, MainStylesheet::class)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(App::class.java, *args)
}
```