# Javafx: Getting rid of Slider margin

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, slider

I have a "slider progress bar hybrid" as described in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159251/1031659) (invisible slider on top of a progress bar with value binding) and my problem is that the slider has a small margin on the left and right side, so that the progress bar is off by a few pixels when the slider thumb is placed near the end of the slider. I tried setting `-fx-background-insets`, `-fx-background-radius` and `-fx-padding` to zero on the slider and the track as well as `Slider#setPadding()`, all to no avail.

How can I get rid of the gaps on either side of the slider's track?

Here's my code so far:

```
StackPane seekSliderStack = new StackPane();

ProgressBar seekProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
seekProgressBar.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

Slider seekSlider = new Slider();
seekSlider.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
seekSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
            Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
    seekProgressBar.setProgress(newValue.doubleValue() / 100);
    }
});
seekSlider.setValue(30);

//seekSlider.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY); // doesn't change anything

seekSliderStack.getChildren().addAll(seekProgressBar, seekSlider);
```

And the css stylesheet:

```
.slider {
    -fx-background-insets: 0; 
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}

.slider .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: null;
}

.slider .track {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-pref-height: 20px;
    -fx-background-insets: 0; 
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-insets: 0; 
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.progress-bar .track{
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.progress-bar .bar { 
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    -fx-background-insets: 0; 
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
```

And finally a little image showing the gaps (white bar is the slider track, red outline belongs to the slider and the blue part is the progress bar on green progress bar track, changed slider height to half the progress bar's and made the slider track visible for demonstration):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wow, found the solution to my problem just minutes after posting the question:

setting `-fx-pref-width` to zero on the slider thumb makes those gaps disappear, which works for me, because I'm hiding the thumb anyway.

I guess it's true that talking (or in this case: writing) about a problem makes it easier to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

With this css i fixed it too:

```
.slider {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0 -10 0 -10;
}

.slider .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: lightblue;
    -fx-pref-width: 20;
    -fx-pref-height: 20;
}

.slider .track {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}

.progress-bar {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.progress-bar .track {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.progress-bar .bar {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
```

[image]